# How to compile .dll with SConstruct using tools = ['mingw']

Tags: c++, linux, dll, mingw, godot

This is the content of the SConstruct file:

```
#!python
import os

cppfiletodll = 'theone.cpp'

env = DefaultEnvironment()
env = Environment(tools = ['mingw'])
env['CXX'] = 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++'

Default(env.SharedLibrary('foo',cppfiletodll))
```

When run with `$ scons` it outputs:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o theone.o -c theone.cpp
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -shared -o libfoo.so theone.o -Wl,--out-implib,libfoo.a
```

And the files I get are:

`theone.o`
`libfoo.a`
`libfoo.so`

I need a `.dll` for Windows, so I adjust the code like below and instead of an `.so` library, it outputs a `.dll`. This .dll **works** on the Windows 10 machine, awesome!

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o theone.o -c theone.cpp
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -shared -o libfoo.dll theone.o -Wl,--out-implib,libfoo.a
```

### TL;DR

So until here, everything works. But I want this automated. So I go back to the `SConstruct` file and add `.dll` suffix like I did for the `console command`.

```
#!python
import os

cppfiletodll = 'theone.cpp'

env = DefaultEnvironment()
env = Environment(tools = ['mingw'])
env['CXX'] = 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++'

Default(env.SharedLibrary('foo.dll',cppfiletodll))
```

But this `SConstruct` file throws an **error**:

```
scons: *** A shared library should have exactly one target with the suffix: .so Target(s) are:libfoo.dll
File "/cppCompileTest/SConstruct", line 10, in <module>
```

**Environment:**
I am working on a GDNative C++ project with Godot Engine. My development machine is Linux, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I can use this .dll library in Godot Engine and successfully compile the application for Windows 10. This application works on Windows 10. I already have an SConstruct file with prefixes, flags and import libraries for Linux. I want to add .dll compiling in this SConstruct file so that I can export libraries for Linux and Windows with just one click. Command line allows me to compile a .dll with mingw but SConstruct does not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
elif env["platform"] == "windows":
    env["SHLIBSUFFIX"] = ".dll"
```

Just stumbled on this exact issue, luckily `print(vars(env))` gave me details on where the offending config was!